# CSS to mimic simple table within div

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have used some AJAX to output HTML to a div.

I thought the AJAX would let me display a table, but since it outputs to a div, turns out, it does not.  `<td>` codes etc. are ignored.  I know that table-less display is considered better, anyway, however I am very weak in CSS.

Can anyone suggest how to display the following simple output without tables.  I mainly need to make columns line up when text is different length.

#### HTML

```
<div id="displayhere"></div>
```

#### Output I would like to go into div except not sure how to put table in div:

```
<tr><td colspan=2>Heading</td></tr>
<tr><td>Short text option 1</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Really long text Option 2</td><td input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Actually, you can *certainly* have a `table` in a `div`. All you have to do is wrap the output in a `tbody` and that `tbody` within an actual `table` element.

Comment: as in <div><table><tbody>...</tbody></table></div>?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Also, table-less display is not always better. Tables are certainly fine and even recommended for tabular data! This depends on what you want to show.

Comment: As @EdD said, use `<table>`s to mark up tables. Use other tags when you’re not marking up a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do, in simplified form is:

```
var output = '<tr><td colspan=2>Heading</td></tr><tr><td>Short text option 1</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr><tr><td>Really long text Option 2</td><td><input type="checkbox"></td></tr>',
    table = $('<table />').appendTo('#displayhere'),
    tbody = $('<tbody />').html(output).appendTo(table);
```

[JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/ezonuy/4/edit).

Answer (score 1):

You can have tables inside div tags..the following works fine

```
<div id="displayhere">
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>Heading</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Short text option 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Really long text Option 2</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox"></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@DavidThomas implies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11393803/20578), you can have an HTML table inside a `<div>`, you just can’t have `<tr>` tags without wrapping them in a `<table>` tag.

I’d note that the HTML you want to insert can also be improved in a couple of ways:

1. There is a tag for heading cells inside tables: `<th>`. If the heading applies to several rows, then you should wrap those rows in a `<tbody>` tag, and set the `scope` attribute of the `<th>` to `rowgroup`
2. When you’re labelling a form control, you should wrap the label text in a `<label>` element, and set the `<label>`’s `for` attribute to the `id` of its form control.

Here’s the improved code. Screen reader users will find it easier to deal with this code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="rowgroup" colspan="2">Heading</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="option1">Short text option 1</label></td>
        <td><input id="option1" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="option2">Really long text Option 2</label></td>
        <td><input id="option2" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```